# Docker running ubuntu with elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, docker, ports

I have a ubuntu docker. I install elasticsearch service it.

When i use the command "curl -X GET 'localhost:9200' ", it return me the version, the name, all right.

It means the elasticsearch is configured correct, but when i access on my browser out of docker , doesn't work.

I have already configured the network  on elasticsearch.yml file in path:
/etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml

I don't know the reason.
When i start the docker i use the command:

docker run -it -p 9200:9200 ubuntu/elastic

**Extra information**: the elasticsearch is in ubuntu that it's a docker too. i start the ubuntu, and after that inside the ubuntu's container i start the elasticsearch service.

Comment: What does it mean "it doesn't work" ? Please provide more information (errors, ...)

Comment: in my physical machine i can't acess elasticsearch on browser it's like if is not running the service, but works on dockers

Answer (score 0):

You should use the **official ELS docker image** instead and use the command in the documentation.

From **[ELS documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docker.html)** :

> The Docker image can be retrieved with the following command:
>
> ```
> docker pull docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:5.4.1
> ```
>
> [...]
>
> ### Running Elasticsearch from the command lineedit
>
> **Development modeedit**
>
> Elasticsearch can be quickly started for development or testing use
>   with the following command:
>
> ```
> docker run -p 9200:9200 -e "http.host=0.0.0.0" -e "transport.host=127.0.0.1"
> ```
>
> docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:5.4.1

Comment: i run the docker with this command.
After i try to access but doesn't work.
I try in browser localhost:9200
127.0.0.1:9200
Not work the two options.

Answer (score 0):

By default elasticsearch is listening at `127.0.0.1` so it won't accessible outside the container. In order to be accessible outside container you will have to launch it using:

```
docker run -p 9200:9200 -e "http.host=0.0.0.0" -e "transport.host=127.0.0.1" docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:5.4.1
```

This will make elasticsearch available on all IP addresses `0.0.0.0` then you will be able to access it. Detail can be found [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docker.html).

Comment: i run the docker with this command.
After i try to access but doesn't work.
I try in browser localhost:9200
127.0.0.1:9200
Not work the two options.

Comment: @kkeaemen by any chance you are running this on Windows/Mac?

Comment: No , on Ubuntu.

Comment: This is super weird because it works for me. Can you make sure elasticserach is listening of all the IPs. Try installing netstats in container and check the IPs on which elastic serach service is running?